# password Regex not matching if spaces around in plain text

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Building a regex to match passwords stored in plain text.
8-15 characters, must contain at least:

- 1 uppercase letter `[A-Z]`
- 1 lowercase letter `[a-z]`
- 1 number `\d`
- 1 special character `[!@#\$%\^&\*]`

The problem I have is when the password is inline with other text or spaces after, it doesn't return a match. When it's on its own without spaces it matches.

**Example:**
This is a Testing!23 surrounded by other text.
Testing!23

```
(?=.{8,15})(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*
```

Comment: I understand you want to find all non-whitespace chunks matching the conditions you outlined, right? Try [`(?<!\S)(?=\S{8,15}(?!\S))(?=[^!@#$%^&*\s]*[!@#$%^&*])(?=[^\s\d]*\d)(?=[^\sa-z]*[a-z])(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z])\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/oRitlE/3).

Comment: Works perfect Wiktor!

Comment: Try this:    `(?=\S{8,15})(?=[^\s]*\d)(?=.*[!@#\$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\S+`
https://regexr.com/3r9av

Comment: `(?=\S{8,15})(?=[^\s]*\d)(?=[^\s]*[!@#\$%^&*])(?=[^\s]*[a-z])(?=[^\s]*[A-Z])\S+` 
Let me know if that works for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find all non-whitespace chunks matching the conditions you outlined.

Use

```
(?<!\S)(?=\S{8,15}(?!\S))(?=[^!@#$%^&*\s]*[!@#$%^&*])(?=[^\s\d]*\d)(?=[^\sa-z]*[a-z])(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z])\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oRitlE/3)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string should be  right before the current position
- `(?=\S{8,15}(?!\S))` - right after the current position, there must be 8 to 15 non-whitespace chars followed with either whitespace or end of string
- `(?=[^!@#$%^&*\s]*[!@#$%^&*])` - there must be a char from the `[!@#$%^&*]` set after zero or more non-whitespace chars outside of the set
- `(?=[^\s\d]*\d)` - there must be a digit after 0+ non-whitespace and non-digit chars
- `(?=[^\sa-z]*[a-z])` - 1 lowercase letter must appear after 0+ chars other than whitespace and lowercase letters
- `(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z])` - 1 uppercase letter must appear after 0+ chars other than whitespace and uppercase letters
- `\S+` - all checks are over, and if they succeed, match and consume 1+ non-whitespace chars (finally).